# I need to filter a range and copy a column to another sheet only if that column is empty

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In google sheet .
I need to filter a range by a-z and copy a column to another sheet only if that column is empty if not, move to the next column.
Something like this :

```js
function AutoSortOnEdit3(){
  // select active sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // select correct sheet
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Edit");

  // select range (exclude top row)
  var range = sheet.getRange("I8:O21");

  // actually do the sorting
  range.sort({column: 9, ascending: true});

}
```

after the filter copy O8:O21 to sheet 2 in B4:B17 but if B4:B17 is not empty copy to C4:C17 and the same if c not empty.
After this, something like this

```js
function AutoSortOnEdit3(){
  // select active sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // select correct sheet
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Edit");

  // select range (exclude top row)
  var range = sheet.getRange("I8:O21");

  // actually do the sorting
  range.sort({column: 11, ascending: true});
```

mean to go back like was before script begin.
I'm a little noob at this, so i'm sorry for bad explanation.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I assume you want to *sort* the range by a column and then *append* the row to the right hand end of Sheet2. Right now it sounds like you want to copy empty columns to Sheet2

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
function appendColVector(sheet, data) {
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, sheet.getLastColumn() + 1, data.length, 1);
  range.setValue(data);
}
```

Then you can call

```
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
appendCol(targetSheet, range.getValues());
```

In `AutoSortOnEdit3`